# Angular2 + material - How to load form?

Tags: forms, angular, spinner, loading, loader

I am using material indeterminate spinner in my angular2 app.

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples

How should I show this spinner, when user press send button in form.

Should I cover form with spinner?
Make some transition form -> spinner?
Or something else?

After successfully request it will change route to another view.

Comment: you are looking for a loading screen i guess till the form submits data to a service and the route is successfull, i guess you should look at router resolve and router events that should work out just fine

Answer (score 1):

I find one of the most visually pleasing and best working ways to manage this sort of event is to implement a loading div on the same level as the form, and use `ngIf` on your form's div with click actions that swap state on submit click:

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <form *ngIf="!isSubmitted">
    ...
    <buttom type="submit" (click)="isSubmitted=true;">
  </form>
  <div class="loading-div" *ngIf="isSubmitted">
    <md-spinner></md-spinner><br>
    Submitting data...
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the general HTML template structure, but there are a few things you'll want to make note of:

- You will likely want your form to call a method on submit which makes `isSubmitted=true`.
- You can make `.loading-div { width: 100%, height: 100%, z-index: 100 }` as long as your parent-div class is typed. This will also allow you to add a class to your spinner and place it in the center of the div.
- This method also prevents duplicate submissions of forms.
- It may be preferred to only add the `*ngIf` to the loading container, and instead add `[disabled]="isSubmitted"` to your submit button. Using this method you can use a transparent background to still show the data, but clearly express the form has been submitted.